# Facebook Graph API - Get posts and reviews about Place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm trying to get posts about Place and reviews about Place whos fb page can look like this :
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Moscow-State-Pedagogical-University/187774447919438

I dont have page access token.
Is that possible to get Page Access Token of Place page at all?

I tried (with user and app token):
1)"/tabs/review" 
2)"/feed"
3)"/posts"
But the return data variable is empty.

4)"/tagged"
This one return data, but result is not what I need.

What can I do to get this posts and reviews? 
Is it impossible?

Comment: Have you tried using the `ratings` page endpoint?

Comment: You can only get page access tokens for pages you have admin access to. And reading the ratings/reviews of a page requires a page access token. Ratings/reviews of pages you do not have admin access to, sinply are none of your business.